# Spring Cloud Stream - Give Serdes to Individual Consumers/Producers

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, deserialization, spring-cloud-stream

I am trying to put individual Serdes on each of my consumers, not all of them. For instance this adds Avro Deserializer to all consumers in my application. I only want it on one consumer

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.consumerProperties.value.deserializer=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
```

If I do something like this it works

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.scheduler-in-from-external-event.content-type=application/*+avro
```

but there doesn't seem to be a way to specify a Serde for a single consumer/producer, i.e.

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.scheduler-in-from-external-event.consumer.configuration.key.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer

spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.scheduler-in-from-external-event.consumer.configuration.value.deserializer=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
```

this doesn't work am I missing a dependency or can someone point me in the direction of specifying a serde for a single producer/consumer in my properties file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Serdes are specified on streams-specific binding properties `...kafka.streams.bindings...`.

Use

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.scheduler-in-from-external-event.consumer.key-serde=...
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.scheduler-in-from-external-event.consumer.value-serde=...
```

Docs here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/docs/3.0.8.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_kafka_streams_consumer_properties